# How to href link to a file that's in a folder outside of the folder my file is in?

Tags: html, file, hyperlink, directory, parent

My files are set up like this:

```
                               Root
                                 |
          tours----------------about----------------gallery
            |                    |                     |
       tour1.html            about.html           gallery.html
```

I want to link the about.html page to the tour1.html page.  Is this possible?

I've tried multiple things and I just can't figure it out. I know that if it were in the same folder I could use `<a href="about.html">` and if it was in the root folder I could use `<a href="..//about.html">` but neither of those are working.

Comment: There are at least two ways to do it, but you've neglected to show what you've tried.... showing what you've tried is a bit of a cardinal requirement here - and also it can lead to you learning something rather than being spoon-fed an answer.

Comment: Showing what you tried (by editing your question and putting it there) is even more important now, since according to a comment you left (on a since-deleted answer), what you say you tried does work correctly... so it would be best for you to reproduce your failure and then post what is not working.

Answer (score 9):

When working with directories in a lot of places, such as some command line prompts (shells) and other applications, it's very useful to know that using `/` at the beginning of the the path will traverse to the home directory from any level, while `../` will traverse to the parent directory of the directory you're in.

For example, if I were creating a link from `http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html` to `http://www.example.com` I could simply use `<a href="/">Home</a>`.

If I wanted to create a link from `http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html` to `http://www.example.com/path/file.html` I could use `<a href="../file.html">File</a>` or `<a href="/path/file.html">File</a>`.

Finally, if I wanted to create a link from `http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html` to `http://www.example.com/file.html` I could use either `<a href="../../file.html">File</a>` or `<a href="/file.html">File</a>`.

So for your example you could use either `<a href="/tours/tour1.html">` (starting from the root) or `<a href="../tours/tour1.html">` (going up one folder and then down into the tours folder).

Answer (score -1):

There are different methods

You could use ../ each time to go back one step in your directory and then target your file.

Or(if you are familiar with node/express or ejs templates) you could directly target /filename as you specified in your app.get("/filename",.....

Answer (score -4):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I tried out an absolute path instead of a relative path and it worked, so I'm just going to work with that instead.

Comment: This can be posted as a comment but as it does not answer the question, it should not be posted as an answer (and should instead be deleted). However, as there is an answer that has helped you, please "accept" and/or "up vote" that answer, using the links next to it (the check, and the up arrow).